# How many domains can a character have?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, domains

An exercise of thought:

Let's say I wanted to make a level 20 multi-class abomination of a character. What classes would I take to give me access to the most domains?

Only looking for Paizo material. Partial access like bloodline powers or bonus spells can be mentioned.

Also, let's ignore how many deities would I have to worship.

Comment: What material is allowed?

Comment: Also, do powers-without-bonus-spells (like godclaw Hell knights) count? Do bonus spells without powers (like the Divine Bloodline sorcerer) count?

Comment: I’ll edit the question

Comment: There are many class features that are like domains (mysteries, patrons, oathbound paladin's oath, etc). You pick a path, it gives you some limited abilities and extra spells. Do those count too?

Comment: @MikeQ no, just looking for Cleric domains. Good question though

Comment: What about the Warpriest's [blessings](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/warpriest/blessings/) or the [Divine Scion's feature "Domain Specialization"](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/c-d/divine-scion/)?  They involve choosing domains, but they don't give domain abilities per se.

Comment: @MikeQ I’ll pass on those too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well for starters, we can get to **9** domains with an 11th level character.

Cleric 1 / Druid 1 / Hunter 3 / Paladin 4 / Occultist 1 / Medium 1.

- Cleric = +2 domains

At first level, a chooses two [domains](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Cleric/domains) granted by their deity. There are some alignment-based restrictions, but otherwise the choices are limited by the deity you chose.

- Druid = +1 domain

A 1st level druid gets the [Nature Bond](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/#TOC-Nature-Bond-Ex-) class feature, and choose either an animal companion or a cleric's domain. The choices are limited, although some of the splat books (Ultimate this, Ultimate that) enable more domain choices.

- Inquisitor = +0 domains

Just kidding! If you have levels in cleric, then you can't dip into [Inquisitor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/) to get an extra domain.

> If the inquisitor has cleric levels, one of her two domain selections must be the same domain selected as an inquisitor. Levels of cleric and inquisitor stack for the purpose of determining domain powers and abilities, but not for bonus spells.

- Hunter ([Divine Hunter](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/hunter/archetypes/paizo-hunter-archetypes/divine-hunter/) archetype) = +1 domain

At 3rd level, this Hunter archetype lets them choose an additional domain. Unlike the inquisitor, there are no restrictions if you multiclass.

> At 3rd level, a divine hunter learns to call upon the power of her deity. The divine hunter must select one domain from those available to her deity. She gains the granted powers of this domain, using her hunter level – 2 as her cleric level for determining when the powers are gained and what effects they have. Once she chooses this domain, it cannot be changed.

- Paladin ([Sacred Servant](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin/archetypes/paizo-paladin-archetypes/sacred-servant/) or [Temple Champion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin/archetypes/paizo-paladin-archetypes/temple-champion/) archetype) = +1 domain

Either option involves a 4th level paladin. Sacred Servant lets you pick a cleric domain and get the additional spells, whereas the Temple Champion lets you pick a cleric domain and get the 1st level domain power. Both seem to qualify here.

- Occultist ([Reliquarian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/occultist/archetypes/paizo-llc-occultist-archetypes/reliquarian-occultist-archetype/) archetype) = +1 domain

Occultists are weird, and this one is weirder because it's also a divine caster.

> A reliquarian gains access to one of her deity’s domains. She treats her occultist level as her cleric level for the purposes of access to domain powers and their strength. Additionally, the reliquarian adds the domain’s spells to her occultist spell list and her spells known.

- Medium ([Wendo Caller](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/medium/archetypes/paizo-llc-medium-archetypes/wendo-medium-archetype/) archetype) = +1 domain

Even weirder than the Occultist, this Medium archetype can choose a different domain each day. There are plenty of options. You gain the domain powers and the domain spells.

> While channeling a wendo, the wendo caller gains the 1st-level domain power of one druid animal or terrain domain, or the 1st-level domain power of one of the following cleric domains: Air, Animal, Community, Darkness, Death, Destruction, Earth, Fire, Healing, Knowledge, Protection, Rune, Strength, Sun, Trickery, War, Water, or Weather.
>
> The wendo caller has an effective cleric or druid level equal to 1/2 his medium level (minimum 1st) for the purpose of this ability. In addition, he adds all spells from his chosen domain that are of a spell level he can cast (including modifications to the wendo caller’s spellcasting from the archmage arcana or divine surge lesser spirit powers) to his medium spell list and medium spells known as medium spells of their domain spell level.

- Feats = +2 domains

The *Advanced Class Guide* introduced [Believer's Boon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/believer-s-boon), a loosely worded feat. Pick a deity, get one of their domains. There are no restrictions if you're already a cleric. Plus, you can take this feat at 1st level and again at 3rd level, for a sum total of two additional domains.

> When you take this feat, choose one domain granted by your deity. You can use the 1st-level domain ability that clerics of that domain can use a number of times or rounds per day, but you can use it only once per day or 1 round per day, whichever is appropriate. Your effective cleric level in regard to this ability is 1st level. If the domain has a 1st-level ability that does not meet this specification, you cannot use it.
>
> Special: You can take this feat twice. When you take it a second time, you choose another domain granted by your deity.

Total = **2 + 1 + 1 + 1 +1+ 1 + 2 = 9**

**Not included, because they aren't "Domains":**

- Warpriest's [Blessings](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/warpriest/blessings/): Warpriest chooses two of their deity's domains, but they get Blessings instead of domain abilities.
- Ranger (Divine Tracker)'s [Blessings](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/archetypes/paizo-ranger-archetypes/divine-tracker/): Same problem as warpriest. You pick a deity's domains, but get warpriest minor blessings.
- Wizard's [Arcane School](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/): Like a domain, it grants limited abilities, and an additional spell per day per level.
- Shaman's [Spirits](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/shaman/spirits/): Like a domain, it grants limited abilities, and an additional spell per day per level. Also a divine caster.
- Witch's [Patrons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/witch-patrons/): Like a cleric, witches get their powers from a patron, which also gives them additional spells known, but not additional spells per day.
- Divine Scion's [Domain Specialization](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/c-d/divine-scion/): Pick a domain, and gain a spell-like ability. It doesn't function like a cleric domain.
- Bard (Faith Singer)'s [Devout Spell Knowledge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/archetypes/paizo-bard-archetypes/faith-singer/): Pick a domain, and gain some spell-like abilities. Doesn't function like a cleric domain.

Answer (score 7):

## All of them

A properly built [Sacrament Alchemist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/archetypes/paizo-alchemist-archetypes/sacrament-alchemist/) 20 can gain access to the powers of all domains and subdomains simultaneously, each as a 20th level Cleric.  Since it takes nothing away from the domain access, however, we will explore a related build: a Cleric 1/Planar Extremist 1/Wendo Caller 1/Hellknight 9/Reliquarian 1/Sacred Servant 4/Sacrament Alchemist 3.

The deity this character worships is Iomedae, qualifying her simultaneously for the Order of the God Claw, the Paladin class, and the Planar Extremist Druid ex-Class, as well as granting access to more in-deity domains and subdomains than any other deity.

The levels in Planar Extremist, Reliquarian, and Sacred Servant aren't super important.  They each just give us one Iomedae domain, and Sacred Servant gives us (most of) the BAB we need for Hellknight.

The level in Cleric gives us two domains, and qualifies us to be able to use an *Icon of Aspects* to replace any domain with any other domain for a day with a UMD check to impersonate a cleric of a different deity.  As a member of the Order of the God Claw, we *might* (depending on the interpretation of the Reckoning and the *Icon*'s description) be able to access the domains of Abadar, Asmodeus, Irori, and Torag in addition to those of Iomedae, even without a UMD check. If so, that's 13 new domains without a UMD check.  This also allows us to swap out first level powers from things that only give us those for higher level powers if we want.

The level in Wendo Caller gives us access to one domain from a big list of domains that are off-deity, and we can change it each day.

The levels in Hellknight give us access to the Order of the God Claw, through which we can select the Pentamic Faith Discipline 3 times, and consequently get 9 domains (from almost the same set as via our *icon of aspects*).

The levels in Sacrament Alchemist let us use other people's mutagens if we want, and makes our mutagen give a domain instead of normal.  For the purposes of the domain added by this ability, all our class levels stack.

For our feats, we are going to want two copies of Believer's Boon, for two more domains.  We are also going to want Leadership, Dynasty Founder(uncompleted), Noble Imposter(completed), and possibly Vile Leadership (if Asmodeus's association with the Order of the God Claw can make it count as an Evil Organization).  As a 20th level character, having the charisma needed to max out Leadership is trivial; we hit the cap with a Charisma of 8 even before special leadership modifiers.

Our 405 1st level sacrament alchemist followers can then each imbibe their respective cognatogens, then use the spell *mutagenic touch* via sentient magic items crafted by our higher-level followers to pass the effects of the cognatogen onto us-- while drinking a mutagen ends the effects of previously imbibed mutagens, mutagenic touch merely transfers the effects.  This lets us gain up to 405 domains and subdomains of our choice, but unfortunately there are only around 200 published 1st-party domains and subdomains.

We also definitely want to take the acolyte of apocrypha trait, so we can get a couple of those subdomains that we otherwise wouldn't be allowed to.

Comment: This is a very cool build but doesn't quite work. Sacramental cognatogens, unlike similar archetype-specific pseudo-mutagens, don't actually count as mutagens: "Discoveries, feats, and effects that interact with the mutagen class feature do not affect sacramental cognatogen." So Mutagenic Touch can't transfer them.

Comment: Mutagenic Touch also can't let you be under the effects of multiple mutagens; the class feature states "The effects of a mutagen do not stack." Furthermore, the rule you're referring to here on one mutagen ending another states: "Whenever an alchemist drinks a mutagen, the effects of any previous mutagen immediately end." (Notice it doesn't say "previously imbibed".)